# What should I return for an HTTP PUT REST call that results in no changes?

Tags: rest, http, put

I have a resource that is created by POST, then can be updated via PUT.

If someone calls PUT and doesn't change anything, should it still return a 200 and look like the update has been performed (even though nothing was actually updated)?

Comment: `If the target resource does have a current representation and that representation is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed representation, then the origin server MUST send either a 200 (OK) or a 204 (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the request.` ([Source](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)). Loosley speaking, the PUT request replaces the current representation. If it is the same or different does not matter according to the HTTP protocol. If you need a versioning mechanism look at ETag or If-Modified-Since headers

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, 200 is fine. The request was OK and was processed the way it should. There is no semantic status code expressing an operation that did not result in any changes.